# modifying ng-class from directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to write a directive that watches an element's width, and conditionally sets an ng-class variable. Not quite sure if I'm going about this the right way and would appreciate some help! My html

```
    <div ng-class="{'compact' : compact}" calc-width>stuff here</div>
```

My directive (so far)

```
    app.directive('calcWidth', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { 
                var width = elem[0].clientWidth;
                scope.compact = false;
                if (width < 600) {
                    scope.compact = true;
                }
            },
        };
    });
```

Firstly, this isn't modifying the ng-class variable as expected. Secondly, how do I go about 'watching' for changes in the element's width? Normally I could just use the window resize function, but the element's size also changes in other cases such as side panels opening. Should I even be doing this? Or would it be best to somehow trigger this directive from another directive/controller/service which controls the panels?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the contents of your link function inside a `$watch` function.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { 
    scope.$watch(function () { // this function will be executed for each digest cycle.
        var width = elem[0].clientWidth;
        scope.compact = false;
        if (width < 600) {
            scope.compact = true;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Actually, the first argument for `$watch` should only return the `clientWidth`.  The second argument (the change handler) should change `compact`. This won't have good performance anyway. If possible (depending on use case), window onResize should be used instead.

Comment: @Sulthan, As elem(or clientWidth) is not part of scope, it will not have any affect even if pass it as first argument. 
Regarding performance, Yes, accessing clientWidth on each digest cycle is really heavy.

Comment: That's not true. The first argument for a $watch can be a function. You can return anything you like from this function and the return value is what will be dirty-checked by Angular each $digest cycle. It doesn't matter whether the value under watch is on the scope or not, .